# How to insert value from combo box?

Tags: laravel, combobox

I have a combo box with data from model. Now I want to save value from this combo box into my database. when I save it returns the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'type' cannot be null.

Data from this model returns combobox

```php
class TypeProperties extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'type_properties';

     public static $types = [
         'textbox'  =>  'Textbox',
         'textarea' => 'Textarea',
     ];
}
```

Combobox:

```html
<select name="properties" class="form-control" name="type">
      @foreach($asset as $key =>$value)
              <option value="{{$key}}">
                    {{$value}}
               </option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Function save:

```php
function addPro(Request $req){
      $id = $req->type_id;
      $type = AssetType::find($id);
      $pro = new TypeProperties;
      $pro->name         = $req->name;
      $pro->code         = $req->code;
      $pro->type         = $req->type;
      $pro->assettype_id = $req->type_id;
      $pro->save();
      return redirect(url($type->id.'/add/property'))->with('message','Save successful');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try
    print_r($req->type);

In your function addPro() to check weather the value get posted form form or not.
how r u submitting the form r u using ajax or form submittion ?

Comment: The result returned from combobox is null. I use form submit.

Comment: you have put name attribute two times in select tag pls check and remove the name attribute ="properties" from it

Comment: oh, I see it, now I can save it. Thanks a lots.